# How do I loop through saved xml files to parse address?

Tags: xml, vb.net, loops, file

I run a small construction company and made some basic VB software to store customer querys & basic info. It simply creates a new XML file for each person and stores them locally.

I am trying to add in a section to look up a customer by address, which will need to loop through each .xml file in the directory & check the  tag to see if it matches. If it does match then it opens that file.

I am pretty lost and not sure how I go about this. Does anyone have any clue how I can do this?

Many thanks

Comment: The search function in windows explorer doesn't do what you need?

Comment: Why are you storing in separate XML files instead of just using an Access database? That would be the proper solution, and would be much simpler than what you're doing now, and would make working with the data much more efficient and secure. You can use Access DBs directly from VB.Net quite easily.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Find the files?, Store the file names? Open and parse the XML? Doesn't the [Directory.EnumerateFiles Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=net-5.0) do what you need? And this: [XDocument Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Ken white - I have never heard of an access DB. My programming knowledge is very limited as it’s not my field but I’ve dabbled with VB. how do I go about making an AcessDB?

Comment: There are better alternatives like SQLite (a database). Here is just one of thousands of introductions to the theme: [Using SQLite in a C# Application](https://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_data/using-sqlite-in-a-c-application.html). A database requires more knowledge than individual XML files, but at the end of the day you will have a better, faster, and more scalable solution. Maybe even easier to use once you have acquired the knowledge (which is a too broad theme to give you an answer here).